# How to draw border between rows when first 4 characters in cell of specific column change?

Tags: excel, vba

So I currently use a coded macro that draws a border line when the value in a chosen column changes.

```
Sub AddBorderLineWhenValueChanges()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim xrg As Range
    LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    For Each xrg In Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
        If xrg <> xrg.Offset(1, 0) Then
            Range("A" & xrg.Row & ":Z" & xrg.Row).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End If
    Next xrg
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I need something similar, but rather than look at everything in the cell, it should only look at the first 4 characters. Also, these cells have a mix of text and numbers. I greatly appreciate any help I can get!

Also I apologize if this or a very similar question has been asked before. If so, I'd appreciate it if anyone could comment to links to the other questions and I can use them to figure this out. :)

Comment: `If Left(xrg,4)<> left(xrg.Offset(1, 0),4) Then`

Comment: Yay it worked! Thank you so much!!